# gnome control center shows only a few icons

Tags: gnome, i3-wm

When using `gnome-control-center`, it shows only a few icons, like this:

[image]

I am using i3 and I am calling `gnome-settings-daemon` on start. Should I start any other daemons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start `unity-settings-daemon` instead of `gnome-settings-daemon`.

Comment: That didn't fix my issue. I do have `unity-settings-daemon` running (I can see it with `ps aux`)  but `gnome-control-center` starts with the same few items ("Backups" instead of "Firewall Configuration" in my case, all others the same).

Answer (score 2):

Invoke `gnome-control-center` from the terminal like so:

```
$ env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME gnome-control-center
```

This would launch it the traditional way. And you will be able to navigate through the various settings.